# ChartJS 2.0 Rotation

Tags: html, canvas, chartjs

Como eu posso rotacionar o texto?

O que eu tenho:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentado rotacionar mas o `ctx.translate` não funciona direito, vejam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é meu código:

```
animation: {
                        onComplete: function () {
                            var chartInstance = this.chart;
                            var ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
                            ctx.textAlign = "center";
                            ctx.font = "bold 25px Arial";
                            ctx.fillStyle = "white";
                            ctx.translate(0,1000);
                            ctx.rotate(-0.5*Math.PI);
                            Chart.helpers.each(this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                                var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
                                Chart.helpers.each(meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
                                    ctx.fillText(dataset.data[index], bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 36);
                                }),this)
                            }),this);
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa mesmo da legenda? Pois quando passa o mouse em cima de cada barra, é exibida a legenda... Procure inserir esta configuração no script:

```
 options: { 
         legend: 
                { 
                 display: false 
                } 
          }
```

Assim não será exibida inicialmente, somente quando é passado o mouse em cima de cada barra.